# Why am I getting this error message in a 'load data' line (pic)?

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I am trying to run some code but keep getting an error message about line 76, load("instdata/legosets.rda"). Do you know what I need to change, or if there is something missing?

Thanks for any tips. Pic below with some context.

[place where i'm getting an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuK52.png)

Comment: It says "it cannot open the connection" to the file, which means your specified path is probably wrong. Perhaps you want the extension to be `.rdata` or `.rds`, or the working directory is not correct?

Comment: You can check the path with `list.files("instdata")` to see if the file is listed and you can check your current working directory with `getwd()` to make sure you are starting where you think you are.

Comment: Thanks @CalumYou and @dcarlson! Fixed it :)